# What is the Syntax error StyleCop is complaining about?

Tags: c#, resharper, stylecop

Working with code from Jon Skeet's [MiscUtil library](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/miscutil/), I came across this constructor:

```
public SmartEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    if (enumerable == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException ("enumerable");
    }

    this.enumerable = enumerable;
}
```

I have both ReSharper and the StyleCop extension installed. I was curious to see what the R# suggestion here would be. It was simplifying the code to the following:

```
public SmartEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    this.enumerable = enumerable ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(enumerable));
}
```

StyleCop however has immediately complained with an error message:

> A syntax error has been discovered in file SmartEnumerable.cs [StyleCop Rule: SA0102]

I am working on a .NET Standard 1.6 project with VS2017.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StyleCop does not support [all of the latest C# language features](https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop/issues/73). *This particular behaviour you have found is a [known issue](https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop/issues/92).*

I'd recommend you switch to [StyleCop Analyzers](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers).